# Facebook php-sdk v4 get friend list

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

i'm using new facebook php sdk v4 and I want to retrieve full list of friends 
Code:

```
try {

$user_friends = (new FacebookRequest(
  $session, 'GET', '/me/friends'
))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

echo '<pre>';
print_r($user_friends);

 } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

}
```

But the result is:

```
Facebook\GraphUser Object
 (
[backingData:protected] => Array
    (
    )
  )
```

Login url parameters:

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array( 'publish_actions', 'user_friends', 'public_profile' ) );
```

Is this feature is disabled? There is another way to get a list of friends?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You will get only those friends who are using same Facebook application.

```
\Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('id','secret');

$session = new \Facebook\FacebookSession('access_token');

// Check user's token is valid or not.
$me = (new \Facebook\FacebookRequest(
$session, 'GET', '/me/friends'
))->execute()->getGraphObject(\Facebook\GraphUser::className());

$result = $me->asArray();

// Get user's friends
$friends = $result['data'];

// Converting classes to array
foreach ($friends as $key => $value) {
    $friends[$key] = (array)$value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer here [retrieve full list of friends using facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507885/retrieve-full-list-of-friends-using-facebook-api/23510232#23510232)

The edge `/{user-id}/friends` only return friends which have used the same app as the requesting user: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends/

Please make sure that you use the search functionality of SO before you post a question next time, because there were already lots of question regarding the same topic.

Comment: Thank you, I searched but did not find this post. So I have to send an application for review to be able to retrieve friends data(like first name, last name)? This is the only option?

Comment: If you're using v2.0 of the Graph API, you cannot access friends information other than those given by `/{user-id}/friends`, `/{user-id}/taggable_friends` and `/{user-id}/invitable_friends` which are not much. Friends permissions have been removed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Comment: Thanks but i have other problem, on index.php page if i check user's session I can see that I'm logged in, but in other.php I'm not logged in. I use this same code in both files.

Comment: That's not related to your question.

Comment: Sorry, posted new question.