# Facebook Graph Api: trying to get logged user all friends list is failed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get logged user friends list, through Facebook Login with accepted permissions. As i understand it returns only those users who are accepted permission of the same app.

But, when i'm just opening https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ , choosing "Graph API explorer" and entering -> /me/friends i get just three random friends. Why is it so?

Can someone help to understand how to get all friends of a logged user throug facebook login? Or it's not possible anymore?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids, and there are multiple questions/answers about the same topic during the last days available via the search of Stackoverflow, e.g. [retrieve full list of friends using facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507885/retrieve-full-list-of-friends-using-facebook-api/23510232#23510232)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Facebook API v2.0 /me/friends will only return friends that are using the app and not all friends. And there is nothing you can do to get all friends

If you created your app after 4/30/2014 you have to use v2.0.