# Friends list in facebook api v2.0 in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can i get all friend's list in Facebook api v2.0. I am getting it in v1.0 but in v2.0 it is returning only list of those friends which are already authorised the same app.

I need my all friends list and there DOB using graph api.

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

above request is not giving me all friends data.
Any one can help me out.

Comment: You can't get all friends in API v2.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api v2.0 me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m)

Comment: As @Wizkid said, this is no longer possible.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the search functionality of StackOverflow the next time before you post a question. This has been answered dozens of times before since the announcement of the Graph API v2.0.

Have a look the the answer here for example:

[retrieve full list of friends using facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507885/retrieve-full-list-of-friends-using-facebook-api/23510232#23510232)

In short: `/me/friends` will from May 1st 2014 on only return the friends which use your app.

Answer (score 0):

using "/me/taggable_friends" we can get friend's name and id only. i want their birthday date that is not returned by this call and we can not use id for getting birthday.

Comment: Friends permission have vanished anyway, so you'll not be able to get this data if you use v2.0: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Answer (score -1):

This is the way i requests the Facebook friends list. Hope this helps.

```
   [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                     parameters:nil
                                     HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error){

                 NSLog(@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"data"]);

         }];
```