# My app stated returning empty JSON for facebook graph query, query works for other apps

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, facebook-apps

I have successfully been executing the following query through an IOS app for some time:

```
FB.api('/me/friends?access_token={access_token}',callback());
```

Yesterday the query started returning an empty JSON object

```
{"data":[]}
```

When I go to the graph explorer tool and try this query using my app I get the same result. However if I change to a different app it seems to be working. Does any one know what might have happened to my app to make it suddenly stop working?

I can't see how it's related but around the time the problem started I generated an adobe phoneGap ios build of my app for the first time.

Comment: Please search. In Facebook API v2.0 only friends that are also using the app will be returned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507885/retrieve-full-list-of-friends-using-facebook-api/23510232#23510232