# Fetching friendlist with new Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can anyone tell me how will i be able to fetch the friendlist using a simple HTTP request call like mentioned below,

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=xxxx

This was working for me using the access_token generated before the new update of Graph API on April 30th.

Can anyone help me out in getting this done?

Answer (score 3):

This is like the 50th question about this topic. Please use the search of SO next time first.

It's no longer possible for an app which was created after 30th of April 2014 to get the complete user list. For an app which was created before that, you can prepend `/me/friends` with `/v1.0` to get the friend list. This will only work until 30th April 2015!

My answer to this question: [retrieve full list of friends using facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507885/retrieve-full-list-of-friends-using-facebook-api/23510232#23510232)

Also, see the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api