# Don't get all friends of facebook in my ios app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to get all friend using Facebook integration in my app. i am give `user_friends` permmision at login time. and i use below code to get list of friends.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                          id result,
                          NSError *error
                      ) {
                          NsLog(@"Result = %@",result);
                      }];
```

But i got only that friend which uses my apps. means who installed my apps. but not get all friends of my Facebook . i want all friend of Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're apparantly using Graph API v2.0. If your app was registered after April 30th 2014, you don't have to chance to get all friends via `/me/friends`. This has been discussed here dozens of times, and Facebook docs clearly descibe this.

Have a look at

- [retrieve full list of friends using facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507885/retrieve-full-list-of-friends-using-facebook-api/23510232#23510232)
- [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m)

Answer (score 0):

Graph API V.2.0 Got All friend list As below

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/taggable_friends"
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                              NSLog(@"Toggle friend =%@",result);
                          }];
```