# Facebook Android SDK - Friends Picker not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have started learning FB integration in android tutorials from the facebook developers site. But what I have observed is that the Pick Friends activity in the provided example projects (Sample Projects Scrumptious and HelloFbSample) doesn't work either in the emulator or the smart phone. Is either anybody experiencing the same problem ?

[image]

Comment: Which facebook-sdk version are you using?

Comment: hellow @algo1 i am also face this problem and i also not post photo on facebook, i just to do post message and see pick place, so if you are find solution about pick some friends and post photo,then please share your knowledge to me,in post photo i got error of not getting permission,but i also add extra permission then also not success.so if you find solution now then please help me.

Comment: @NiravMehta Sorry dude.I have left that project and not working on it

Comment: you post image on facebook successfully ??

Comment: @algo1 are you post photo on facebook on that example ?

Comment: No . I didn't do that

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API v2.0 shows only friends who are also using your app. See [Don't get all friends of facebook in my ios app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992387/dont-get-all-friends-of-facebook-in-my-ios-app/23992602#23992602)

Answer (score 0):

Even though The Facebook Platform v2.0 shows only friends who are also using your app, you still may be able to see the entire list of friends provided:

1) You are using older version of facebook sdk, as I am using 3.5, it's working well for me.
2) You must have registered your app in your facebook developer account before April 2014.

This will work only till April 30, 2015. After that the friends who are using the same app only would be visible.

Reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 0):

I have found a few workarounds that will show a users friends, however you cannot interact with them. Like inviting them to your app. Facebook has bascically restricted this kind of behavior to games only but if you read my issue request here on HelloJS you will see i have a few solutions that might help. In no means is this for Java (Android) its for web based/cordova mobile apps not native android (java)

https://github.com/MrSwitch/hello.js/issues/57