# How to get facebook friend list and their id using facebook 3.14 sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I have tried lots of and searched on google .I have also tried using facebook friend picker sample  using https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk this.but I found no friend seen(empty list) .Can anyone suggest for any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the search next time before posting a duplicate qustion, or consult the facebook docs.

With the v2.0 of the Graph API, you can only get the freinds which use the same app. See [Don't get all friends of facebook in my ios app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992387/dont-get-all-friends-of-facebook-in-my-ios-app/23992602#23992602) or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the github project that you've mentioned in the question; but you have to understand this that **you cannot fetch the list of all the friends of a user** with v2.0 Graph APIs (or Android SDK 3.14+).

The official doc of [`/{user-id}/friends`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends) says-

- A user access token with `user_friends` permission is required to view the current person's friends.
- This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.
- If a friend of the person declines the `user_friends` permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.

Learn more about API v2.0 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook-graph-api-v2.0/info).