# Facebook friends request returns only friends with installed app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the list of all user's friends from Facebook, but the request returns only friends with installed app. Here the code:

```
FBRequest *request =  [FBRequest  requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:@{@"fields":@"installed,id,first_name,last_name,location,email"} HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                       NSDictionary* result,
                                       NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"result friends %@",[result objectForKey:@"data"]);
    NSLog(@"error %@",[error description]);
}];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't get all friends of facebook in my ios app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992387/dont-get-all-friends-of-facebook-in-my-ios-app)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api v2.0 me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here: [Don't get all friends of facebook in my ios app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992387/dont-get-all-friends-of-facebook-in-my-ios-app/23992602#23992602)

With Graph API v2.0, you'll only be able to get friends who also use the app. This is by design.