# facebook4j-for accessing full friendlist

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently I have used facebook4j for accessing friend list from facebook. I am able to get rest of the details of user such as username, date of birth, gender, family details, prfile picture URL and so on. But in case of friendlist I am getting only 8 to 9 friends. So, I need access to  full friend list. Below is my code which I have used for accessing friend list.

`FacebookFactory ff = new FacebookFactory(configuration); 
        Facebook facebook = ff.getInstance(); 
                facebook.getFriends();`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api v2.0 me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m)

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses Graph API v2.0, you'll not be able to receive the full list of friends any longer. See [retrieve full list of friends using facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507885/retrieve-full-list-of-friends-using-facebook-api/23510232#23510232) and the included links.

Also, `username` will no longer work.