# Getting null graphobject in facebook respone

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to get facebook friendlist with their profile picture but i didn't get any success in it. Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   

    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback(){

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {

            requestMyAppFacebookFriends(session);

        }

    });


  }

  private Request createRequest(Session session) {
        Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me/friends", null);

        Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>();
        String[] requiredFields = new String[] { "id", "name", "picture"};
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(requiredFields));

        Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
        parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", fields));
        request.setParameters(parameters);

        return request;
    }


  private void requestMyAppFacebookFriends(Session session) {
        Request friendsRequest = createRequest(session);
        friendsRequest.setCallback(new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                List<GraphUser> friends = getResults(response);
               Log.v(TAG, "friends list size "+friends.size());
            }
        });
        friendsRequest.executeAsync();
    }

  private List<GraphUser> getResults(Response response) {
        GraphMultiResult multiResult = response.getGraphObjectAs(GraphMultiResult.class);
        GraphObjectList<GraphObject> data = multiResult.getData();
        return data.castToListOf(GraphUser.class);
    }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
```

The problem i am facing is that when i try to get graphobject response.getGraphObjectAs(GraphMultiResult.class) it returns null. So guide me what i'm doing wrong here or is there is any other way of getting a facebook friend.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're using v2.0 of the Graph API. With that, you'll only get the friends which also use the same app.

See [retrieve full list of friends using facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507885/retrieve-full-list-of-friends-using-facebook-api/23510232#23510232)

Comment: still getting the null response

Comment: Probably because non of your friends use the app!

Comment: so how can i get the list of all the friends even if they don't use the app

Comment: It's simple: You can't.

Comment: you said "none of the  frined use the app" which app you are referening fb-app or mine app?