# Facebook API v2 - Friends ID

Tags: c#, facebook, api

i need to find all my friends's id. On www.developers.facebook.com i have 2 app. The first one have api version 1 and version2, the second one has only api version 2.

With api version 1 I can find all my friends's id with /me/friends but on api version 2 this not work.

On my new Facebook profile I want to create a new app with api version 1, is possible? If I can't how I get all id of my friends?

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed here dozens of times. There are also dozens of answer which you would've been able to find using the Stackoverflow Search.

See [retrieve full list of friends using facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507885/retrieve-full-list-of-friends-using-facebook-api/23510232#23510232) for example.

Creating a new app with Graph API v1.0 is not possible.

Comment: Yes, i've tried to use taggable_friends but i can't retrieve the user id!! How I can do it?

Comment: You can't get the `user_id` via the `taggable_friends` endpoint

Comment: Ok, so you know any method for get the id of all my friends?

Comment: There is none, and this is by design