# Is it possible to use the id from taggable friends api for the see friendship feature?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is going off this thread [retrieve full list of friends using facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507885/retrieve-full-list-of-friends-using-facebook-api). The answer said that "So, in v2.0 you'll only be able to get all friends via the /me/taggable_friends (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends) endpoint, which only contains the fileds id, name, picture, and only can be used after a review of your app by Facebook" and one of the comments said that "You should be aware the even after a review and permission to use taggable_friends, the IDs you get back can only be used to tag friends - you can't use those IDs to get any other information about a user." Does that mean that I would not be able to use see friendship with the id from taggable friends? Usually for see friendship, you go to it by going to this url https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=person1Id&and=person2Id

Would the ids from taggable friends work as parameter vales and and?
Would that be a case of using that id to get information about a user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taggable_friends can only be used to tag people. You can not use it for anything else.

Comment: so no to share friendship? thats what I thought too.

Comment: Is sharing friendship tagging people? No it is not